# create list of Integers in java - cant use new List<Integer>();

Tags: java, list

What is wrong with the statement?

```
    List<Integer> phDigits = new List<Integer>();

Error: Cannot instantiate the type List <Integer>
```

Yes I know i can use `new ArrayList<Integer>()` instead - I'm asking why the first statement dosen't work.

EDIT:  this was a valid question I had.. too simple for SO standards?

Comment: `List` is an interface.

Comment: You need to use concrete class for substantiation. For example, `ArrayList`

Comment: This might have been a valid question, but it has been answers time and time again. We downvote when we judge that you've made or shown no effort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`List` is an interface, which means that other classes can implement it. If a class implements `List`, you can then write

```
List<Integer> something = new ClassThatImplementsList<Integer>();
```

`List` can be used as a type, since anything that implements `List` is a `List`, but you can't say "make a List" in Java since it doesn't know how to. All `List` does is provide the methods you must implement, but it does not contain the implementations.

Answer (score 3):

List is an interface. You cannot instantiate it. 
This is the problem. It's not that it doesn't work, 
it won't even compile.